# Should I have the foreign key column in my entity models?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am coming from the Entity Framework over to NHibernate. When looking at how to create my domain entities I noticed that in some of the examples they don't include the column of the foreign key relationship. Since the `Session` class contains a `Load()` method it is possible to just use objects without the trip to the database instead of primary keys. Is this a normal practice when constructing entity models in NHibernate.

**Example Entity**

```
public class BlogPost : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    //Should this be here
    public virtual int AuthorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

**Creating Entity**

```
BlogPost post = new BlogPost
{
    Name = "My first post",
    Author = session.Load<Author>(1) //Avoids hitting the database
};

session.Save(post);
```

-- OR ---

```
BlogPost post = new BlogPost
{
    Name = "My first post",
    AuthorID = 1 //Use the id of the object
};

session.Save(post);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use full entities / objects instead of having foreign keys.

Foreign keys are database concept. They don't make much sense when you are doing object oriented programming. When doing OOP, you are composing objects together. In your case, a `Blog` **has a** collection of `Posts`. `Post` **has a** parent `Blog`, etc.

Entity IDs are just used to uniquely identify entities.

The whole point of [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) should be to allow you to use OOP best practices (Object), database best practices (Relational) and not to mix the concepts between them (that's what Mapping part of the name [stands for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)).

Some ORMs are better than others in following this. Hint: *[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)*.

Comment: I have to disagree with this. Get the data model correct, screw designing your database around your ORM. If you're using a decent ORM, you shouldn't have problems with something like foreign keys, in fact they should make your life easier by allowing the ORM to better understand the structure of your data. For example, in DBIx::Class, a Perl ORM, the presence of foreign keys helps the ORM automatically create relationships between tables that you can use to do automatic joins through simple queries. I admit I don't know the ORM in question, bad smell though...

Comment: @Moses That's how `NHibernate` does things also. ID of the `Author` is used in database as a foreign key from `BlogPosts` table to `Authors` table (or whatever you want to call them). And NHibernate can generate the database schema from your entities (entity mappings in fact). You just don't need to have the actual foreign keys in your entities. Instead of `AuthorId` property you have an instance of `Author`. NHibernate creates correct joins when doing queries.